# Servlet+jQuery/Ajax - Unexpted token o

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, gson

I'm new to developing web applications with Java. I'm trying to establish an AJAX call. This is some arbitrary code that I've created.

Servlet

```
        Map<String, String> testJson = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String Key = "someKey";
    String Value = "someValue";

    testJson.put(Key, Value);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(testJson));
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).on("click","#register-user", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Register',
        success: function(data){
            alert($.parseJSON(data));
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The callback function is working without any Json so the AJAX is fine. But when I try to send back a Java object that is encoded with Json I get an "Uncaught exception. Unexpected token o". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide the contents of `data` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(testJson);
```

or try a little something like this

```
 Type typeOfMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
 String json = gson.toJson(map, typeOfMap);
```

More examples of the above on this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/test/java/com/google/gson/functional/MapTest.java?r=827)

and then return the Stringed JSON

Comment: Can't seem to find the TestTypes class inside of the gson package.